# NPM deprecated issue, please update from 6.8.0 to 6.14

Tags: npm

npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142 npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported C:\Users\Sai\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> C:\Users\Sai\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin\ng C:

Comment: just because libraries are deprecated or no longer supported doesn't mean other libraries aren't still using them.  You might not have anything to fix.

Comment: I saw this as an issue and every newbie developer is facing so thought to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Open your command prompt and uninstall angular/cli by using
"npm uninstall -g angular-cli" command.

Remove the node_modules directory and then clear the cache by using
"npm cache clear --force" command.

Remove
C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm
you can remove the folder this way
rmdir C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\ /s
and
C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache.
you can remove the folder this way
rmdir C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache /s

Now try to install the angular/cli@latest by using npm install -g @angular/cli@latest command.